# Select values from another csv depending on the total from another column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here are two DataFrames A & B I want to select Rows from DataFrames B when you add the Orders, you get the total value matching the canceled column in DataFrames A.  Then create a column in DataFrames A Named id containing the IDs selected from data frame B. The IDs in DataFrames A should total up to the value in column canceled.

```
code    canceled            id
xxx      [11.0]         [128282, 128281, 128284]
```

DataFrame A

```
code       canceled            
xxx        [11.0]           
xxS        [0.0]            
ssD        [1.0]           
cvS        [0.0]            
eeS        [5.0]            
544W       [44.0]           
cvd        [20.0]
```

DataFrame B

```
 id         code     order        
108664      xxS        4
107650      544W       20
115236       eeS        1
128281       xxx        8
128282       xxX        1
127763       544W       4
128014       544W       20
108586       eeS        1
113472       eeS        1
114106       eeS        3
114106       eeS        3
11111        cvd       55
128283       xxx        5
110515       xxS        1
113556       xxS        1
132434       544W       58
128284       xxX        1
```

This is what I tried before but it's not working as I wanted

```
def id_selector(x):

  canc = int(Df_A.canceled[0])
  if canc  >= len(x.id):
    return x.id
  return  x.id

//create new column id on dataFrame B
Df_A['id'] = DF_B.apply(
id_selector, axis = 1
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what didn't work?

Comment: Hi jorijnsmit, sorry i had missed adding my failed solution, please check it out i updated it, thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Coeur, can you help me out on this issue